# VueJS build to folder routes not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a VueJS app with the following configs:

1) config.index.js

```
build: {
// Template for index.html
index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

// Paths
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
assetsPublicPath: '',

/**
 * Source Maps
 */

productionSourceMap: true,
// https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
devtool: '#source-map',

// Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
// Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
// Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
// npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
productionGzip: false,
productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

// Run the build command with an extra argument to
// View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
// `npm run build --report`
// Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
```

}

2) router/index.js

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  // base: process.env.ROUTER_BASE,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorldBase',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/hello',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/auth',
      name: 'Auth',
      component: Auth
    }
  ]
})
```

3) .htaccess

```
## https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html & https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624803
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

After I run: `npm run build`

The dist folder contains the folder: "static" and the index.html file.

If I copy the content of the "dist" folder and the ".htaccess" file to the "vue" folder from my existing website when I run: http://myapp.com/vue/hello or just http://myapp.com/vue/hello, the pages are not loaded, and instead only the content of "index.html" is loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

If I create a virtual machine and point it to the "vue" folder of my website the pages are working well. For example, my virtual machine is http://vue.local. In this case, the http://vue.local/hello page is working.

But when I want to run Vue inside of the other website, the pages don't work, all of them return the content of index.html.

Any help will be great, thanks!

Comment: What are you using to host the site? And what is the "parent" site that you are trying to add it to? Is it just a static site? PHP? Another Vue site?

Comment: I'm using Apache and the other website is written in PHP. But that website doesn't use any .htaccess files.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there are errors with Vue or if Vue is loading at all?

Comment: Good observatiob. My: domain.com/vue/hello creates the Vue App component, and the path is: path:"/vue/hello" instead of path:"/hello". I guess that this might be the problem why the routes are not recognized.

Comment: Ok, yup, the Vue instance is seeing the whole path from the root, not just the portion relative to what your page that actually has Vue on it.

Comment: You should add the above comment to a separate answer (so I'll be able to select it as winner). In this way I found the problem. Using Vue Debug plugin for Chrome I observated that the route is different and I edited the router base to: base: '/vue/', now it works ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Vue instance is seeing the whole path from the root, not just the portion relative to what your page that actually has Vue on it.

The Vue-Router should have some settings on it where you can set the root, or you can change your paths to include the full path in the routes.

Comment: You saved my day :( , is there a work around to avoid that ?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you are hosting the vue app in a subpath, while by default it expects to exist at `/`.
To solve this problem you have to set the [base](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base) option of `vue-router`.

Probably you'll need to set also `assetsPublicPath` in your `config.index.js`

Comment: This is the solution. I found it using Vue Debug plugin for Chrome following Matti Price's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I built my router index.js in a dockerized vue project, but still doesnt work when deployed in production, where as works in development. Everytime i navigate to about screen it returns **404**

```
 Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'landing',
    component: Landing
  } , {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/app/',
  routes
});
```

My docker file looks as below :

```
    FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm clean-install --fix

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build --fix

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```